# Pseudoinverse as a submatrix of matrix inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

Suppose I have a device that can compute 2x2 (complex) matrix inverses. (For now, assume only invertible matrices, $A$, are ever provided as input):

$A\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12}\\
        a_{21} & a_{22}\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

$A^{-1}= \frac{1}{(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21})}\begin{bmatrix}
        a_{22} & -a_{12}\\
        -a_{21} & a_{11}\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

I can use the same device to compute the pseudoinverse of a 2x1 vector (where $^H$ denotes complex conjugate transpose):

$\underline{b}^+=\frac{1}{(\underline{b}^H\underline{b})}\underline{b}^H$

For example, I can achieve this by inputting the following matrix to my matrix inversion device (where $^*$ denotes complex conjugate):

$B= \begin{bmatrix}
        b_{1} & -b^*_2\\
        b_{2} & b^*_1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Since the inverse is:

$B^{-1}= \frac{1}{(\underline{b}^H\underline{b})}\begin{bmatrix}
        b^*_1 & b^*_2\\
        -b_2 & b_1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$

and the first row of the result is $\underline{b}^+$.

My question is whether this is generalisable to larger matrices. For example, if I have a 3x3 matrix inversion device, can I arrange inputs such that I can read off a 3x2 matrix pseudoinverse? Or have I just stumbled upon the only special case?